# use of __cplusplus in python source

Tags: python, c++, c

What is the use of following in the header files in python source

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

Does it means Python provides us to build code using C++ compiler. If yes, then
are there any differences between building the python source using C and C++ compiler

Comment: This means you can build _Python itself_ with a C/C++ compiler.

Comment: I cannot imagine any advantage in using a C++ compiler (for base python) instead of C.  One reason for these might be to allow extension modules written in C++ to use them.  See also http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/python/doc/index.html

Answer (score 5):

The Python API is still pure C. These directives simply allow for the inclusion of the header in C++ code.

The `__cplusplus` macro is defined implicitly when compiling code with a C++ compiler. So this way the `extern "C"` specification is added only when the compiler that sees it will support it.